# Combining different rankings in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to merge different ranking queries to a simple one and only query for performance issues. I tried sum and having clauses but all of them did not worked for me.

```
$kacinci = mysql_query("SELECT ranking FROM
(SELECT 
@rank:=case when bakiye+0 =@s then @rank else @rank+1 end AS ranking,
@s:=bakiye+0, ID
FROM uye , (SELECT @rank:=0,@s:=0) AS i
ORDER BY bakiye+0 DESC
) new_alias WHERE ID='$profilid'");
$kacincix = mysql_fetch_array($kacinci);
$kacincix = $kacincix[0];

//kaç katına hafta
$kackatinahafta = mysql_query("SELECT ranking FROM
(SELECT 
@rank:=case when kackatinahafta =@s then @rank else @rank+1 end AS ranking,
@s:=kackatinahafta, ID
FROM uye , (SELECT @rank:=0,@s:=0) AS i
ORDER BY kackatinahafta DESC
) new_alias WHERE ID='$profilid'");
$kackatinahaftax = mysql_fetch_array($kackatinahafta);
$kackatinahaftax = $kackatinahaftax[0];

//kaç para hafta

$nekadarhafta = mysql_query("SELECT ranking FROM
(SELECT 
@rank:=case when nekadarhafta =@s then @rank else @rank+1 end AS ranking,
@s:=nekadarhafta, ID
FROM uye , (SELECT @rank:=0,@s:=0) AS i
ORDER BY nekadarhafta DESC
) new_alias WHERE ID='$profilid'");
$nekadarhaftax = mysql_fetch_array($nekadarhafta);
$nekadarhaftax = $nekadarhaftax[0];

//kaç katına ay
$kackatinaay = mysql_query("SELECT ranking FROM
(SELECT 
@rank:=case when kackatinaay =@s then @rank else @rank+1 end AS ranking,
@s:=kackatinaay, ID
FROM uye , (SELECT @rank:=0,@s:=0) AS i
ORDER BY kackatinaay DESC
) new_alias WHERE ID='$profilid'");
$kackatinaayx = mysql_fetch_array($kackatinaay);
$kackatinaayx = $kackatinaayx[0];

//kaç para ay

$nekadaray = mysql_query("SELECT ranking FROM
(SELECT 
@rank:=case when nekadaray =@s then @rank else @rank+1 end AS ranking,
@s:=nekadaray, ID
FROM uye , (SELECT @rank:=0,@s:=0) AS i
ORDER BY nekadaray DESC
) new_alias WHERE ID='$profilid'");
$nekadarayx = mysql_fetch_array($nekadaray);
$nekadarayx = $nekadarayx[0];
```

Note: I know `mysql_query` is deprecated but project is built on that function and planned to update soon.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this query:

```
  SELECT ID
, bakiye
, bakiye_rank
, kackatinahafta
, kackatinahafta_rank
, nekadarhafta
, nekadarhafta_rank
, kackatinaay
, kackatinaay_rank
, nekadarayx
, nekadarayx_rank
FROM uye 
--you can rank over count(field value), for example bakiye
join (SELECT bakiye, count(bakiye) c, case when @c1 = count(bakiye) then @r1 when (@r1 := @r1 + 1) and (@c1 := count(bakiye)) then @r1 end AS bakiye_rank 
  from uye, (SELECT @r1 := 0, @c1 := 0) r group by bakiye order by 2 desc) AS r1 on uye.bakiye = r1.bakiye
--you can rank over count(field value) and field value, for example kackatinahafta
join (SELECT kackatinahafta, count(kackatinahafta) c, case when @c2 = kackatinahafta then @r2 when (@r2 := @r2 + 1) and (@c2 := kackatinahafta) then @r2 end AS kackatinahafta_rank 
  from uye, (SELECT @r2 := 0, @c2 := 0) r group by kackatinahafta order by 2 desc, 1 desc) AS r2 on uye.kackatinahafta = r2.kackatinahafta
--you can rank over field value, for example nekadarhafta
join (SELECT nekadarhafta, case when @c3 = nekadarhafta then @r3 when (@r3 := @r3 + 1) and (@c3 := nekadarhafta) then @r3 end AS nekadarhafta_rank 
  from uye, (SELECT @r3 := 0, @c3 := 0) r group by nekadarhafta order by 1 desc) AS r3 on uye.nekadarhafta = r3.nekadarhafta
join (SELECT kackatinaay, case when @c4 = kackatinaay then @r4 when (@r4 := @r4 + 1) and (@c4 := kackatinaay) then @r4 end AS kackatinaay_rank 
  from uye, (SELECT @r4 := 0, @c4 := 0) r group by kackatinaay order by 1 desc) AS r4 on uye.kackatinaay = r4.kackatinaay
join (SELECT nekadarayx, case when @c5 = nekadarayx then @r5 when (@r5 := @r5 + 1) and (@c5 := nekadarayx) then @r5 end AS nekadarayx_rank 
  from uye, (SELECT @r5 := 0, @c5 := 0) r group by nekadarayx order by 1 desc) AS r5 on uye.nekadarayx = r5.nekadarayx
WHERE ID=$profilid
```

Edit:
corrected, added ( )... -[Operator Precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html) 
This: @r2 := @r2 + 1 and @c2 := kackatinahafta
was calculated like this: @r2 := (@r2 + 1 and @c2 := kackatinahafta),
but should be: (@r2 := @r2 + 1) and (@c2 := kackatinahafta)

Comment: It worked but the rankings seem wrong. I think it's because of possible same scores of different users. For scores like 100 120 120 130, it should be 3,2,2,1

Comment: edit: added different rank over for bakiye, kackatinahafta and nekadarhafta. You probably want rank like in 3th example